# How would I write a script that sends 10 ICMP echo requests then after send 10 timestamps

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using the commands `sudo hping3 -1 -c 10 -a <spoofed IP> <dest IP>` and `sudo hping3 -1 -c 10 --icmp-ts -a <spoofed IP> <dest IP>` in the command line but I was wondering how would you do this as a shell script without using -c. If I could get any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `-c` is likely the  better approach since its more concise and easier to read; however, you could use one of bash's [looping constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html#Looping-Constructs) and [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) to accomplish this:

```sh
for _ in ${0..9}; do
    hping3 -1 -c 10 -a <spoofed IP> <dest IP>
done 

for _ in ${0..9}; do
    hping3 -1 -c 10 --icmp-ts -a <spoofed IP> <dest IP>
done
```